# How to make Tkinter File Dialog only display text files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to control what files the Tkinter file dialog displays to the user. I only want the user to be able to see text files, instead of seeing all of the different types of files such as Word or PowerPoint documents.

Is there a way to specify the file type within the `askopenfilename()` function?

**Edit**

I tried to use this code

```
filename=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes='txt')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a `filetypes` argument with `(('text files', 'txt'),)` value.

As per your try -

```
filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(('text files', 'txt'),))
```

Comment: For python 2.7 it should be **with dot before txt** `filetypes=(('text files', '.txt'),)`